# How do I access localhost after upgrading to XAMPP with PHP 7.2.5?

Tags: php, xampp

All of my websites were working perfectly on the earlier version of XAMPP with PHP 5.6, but just yesterday I backed up all my databases and sites and uninstalled the older version and installed XAMPP with PHP 7.2.5 following online instructions. Now when I try to visit my sites using http://localhost/ with the site names like before it takes me to an Index page showing the outer folder and the content of the websites is completely inaccessible. I haven't been able to find a reason for this online.

Should I try using a version of XAMPP with an earlier version of PHP or is there something I can do with the configuration files to correct this problem?

I'm using Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: try to adjust your path to your website in the `xampp/apache/conf/http.conf` file.

Make sure there is a file named `index.html` (default).
If there is a file named `index.php` this one gets prefered.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with the paths to the websites. I hadn't accounted for changes that had occurred when I unzipped the websites within htdocs and once this was accounted for, the sites all functioned perfectly.